# 'dotnet publish' error referencing dependencies in non-existent lib directory

Tags: dll, asp.net-core, nuget, travis-ci, .net-standard

I am trying to deploy a dotnet core web app via Travis CI to a Ubuntu VPS. I am using `dotnet restore && dotnet publish -c release -r ubuntu.16.04-x64` to build before scp-ing over to the server. The build and deploy completes fine on Travis, but when I restart the application service on my server I get errors such as the one below.

`Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package: 'microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery', version: '1.1.1', path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'`

The `*.deps.json` file that gets created as a part of the publish has lines such as those below.

```
"microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery/1.1.1": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection": "1.1.1",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions": "1.1.1",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "1.1.1",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities": "1.1.1",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool": "1.1.0",
      "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
    },
    "compile": {
      "lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll": {}
    }
  },
  "microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization/1.1.1": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "1.1.1",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "1.1.1",
      "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
      "System.Security.Claims": "4.3.0"
    },
    "compile": {
      "lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll": {}
    }
},
```

Those "compile" attributes are what is causing the issue, because if I manually remove the compile attribute for `lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll`, the error now becomes:

`Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package: 'microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization', version: '1.1.1', path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll'`

Why do these compile attributes get created in the `*.deps.json` file? Are they needed? If so, why is the `lib` directory not created when I `dotnet publish`? If not, how can I remove them so that my app runs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I re-read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/) again and noticed one little detail I had been neglecting. I had been deploying all of the contents of `netcoreapp1.1` rather than just the contents of `netcoreapp1.1/publish`. So, my server was executing the .dll in `netcoreapp1.1` rather than the one in `netcoreapp1.1/publish`. That resolved all of my issues.

Comment: Thank for this, what a surprise.